# Specify method paramater class type in 'every' block

Tags: spring, kotlin, mockk

I have a problem when using any() statement inside the save() method (Spring Framework). I get the error:

> Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in inline fun  any( ): T
> Please specify it explicitly.

Is there any way to pass the method parameter so I wouldn't have the error? I tried to pass the object as a parameter but the save() method creates a new object which requires to use any().

```
every { repository.save(any()) } returns classObject
```

Error while passing the object:

> io.mockk.MockKException: no answer found for:
> Repository(#10).save(app.core.model.Class@734a4045)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the function a type parameter by doing `any<Type>()`.

Example:

```kotlin
fun <T> any(defaultValue: T? = null): T? = defaultValue


fun main() {
    val s = any<String>()
    println(s)
    val i = any<Int>()
    println(i)
    val j = any(10) // type inferred from arg
    println(j)
    val k: Int? = any() // type inferred from variable
    println(k)
}
```

Prints:

```
null
null
10
null
```

The reason the type cannot be inferred is that in your case, `save()` probably accepts values of type `Any` so the compiler cannot infer any specific type.

Incidentally, if you need access to `T` inside a generic function, Kotlin allows you to make the [function `reified`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters).